# Trigger postgresql

Tags: postgresql, триггер

[image]

помогите мне написать Триггер на postgresql

`AFTER INSERT gps_old` insert data in `gps`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: не понимаю как будет на моем случае, можете написать пример

Comment: опишите Вашу задачу, что Вы хотите сделать? и вместо картинок обычно включают скрипты!

Comment: @TigranMkrtchyan научитесь задавать нормальные и понятные вопросы, чтобы вам могли помочь, а не пытайтесь умничать

Comment: @Tigran Mkrtchyan, научитесь читать документацию, тогда сразу и понимание придет

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_gps() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $gps$
    BEGIN

        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO gps (lat, long, speed, course, "time", "date", imei, engine, battery_low, sos, battery_supply) 
                        VALUES (NEW.Lat, NEW.Long, NEW.Speed, NEW.Coure, NEW."Time", NEW."Date", NEW."IMEI", NEW."Engine",  NEW.Lowbattery, NEW.SOS, NEW.Battery);
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$gps$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit
AFTER INSERT  ON "GPS"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_gps();
```